# How to use Workload identity to access ESP in the Google Kubernetes Engine with the Google Cloud .NET SDK?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

**Background**

On the Google Kubernetes Engine we've been using Cloud Endpoints, and the Extensible Service Proxy (v2) for service-to-service authentication.

The services authenticate themselves by including the bearer JWT token in the `Authorization` header of the HTTP requests.

The identity of the services has been maintained with GCP Service Accounts, and during deployment, the Json Service Account key is mounted to the container at a predefined location, and that location is set as the value of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var.

The services are implemented in C# with ASP.NET Core, and to generate the actual JWT token, we use the Google Cloud SDK (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet, and https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client), where we call the following method:

```cs
var credentials = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
```

If the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is correctly set to the path of the Service Account key, then this returns a `ServiceAccountCredential` object, on which we can call the `GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()` method, which returns the actual JWT token.

```cs
var jwtToken = await credentials.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://other-service.example.com/");
var authHeader = $"Bearer {jwtToken}";
```

This process has been working correctly without any issues.

The situation is that we are in the process of migrating from using the manually maintained Service Account keys to using [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) instead, and I cannot figure out how to correctly use the Google Cloud SDK to generate the necessary JWT tokens in this case.

**The problem**

When we enable Workload Identity in the container, and don't mount the Service Account key file, nor set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var, then the `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()` call returns a `ComputeCredential` instead of a `ServiceAccountCredential`.
And if we call the `GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()` method, that returns a token which is not in the JWT format.

I checked the implementation, and the token seems to be retrieved from the Metadata server, of which the expected response format seems to be the standard OAuth 2.0 model (represented in [this model class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/Responses/TokenResponse.cs)):

```
{
  "access_token": "foo",
  "id_token": "bar",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  ...
}
```

And the `GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()` method returns the value of `access_token`. But as far as I understand, that's not a JWT token, and indeed when I tried using it to authenticate against ESP, it responded with

```
{
 "code": 16,
 "message": "JWT validation failed: Bad JWT format: Invalid JSON in header",
 ..
}
```

As far as I understand, normally the `id_token` contains the JWT token, which should be accessible via the `IdToken` property of the `TokenResponse` object, which is also accessible via the SDK, I tried accessing it like this:

```
var jwtToken = ((ComputeCredential)creds.UnderlyingCredential).Token.IdToken;
```

But this returns `null`, so apparently the metadata server does not return anything in the `id_token` field.

**Question**

What would be the correct way to get the JWT token with the .NET Google Cloud SDK for accessing ESP, when using Workload Identity in GKE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an IdToken for the attached service account, you can use `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault().GetOidcTokenAsync(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes Passing, this indeed seems to work! Can I have one more question? Previously with the SA key files, both the `iss` and `sub` fields in the JWT were the email of the SA, for example `"iss": "my-service@foo.com", "sub": "my-service@foo.com"`. But with Workload identity the `iss` is always `https://accounts.google.com`. Is this expected, and we have to adjust the OpenApi specs on the other side to accept this issuer instead?

Comment: Sorry @Johannes Passing, can I ask one more question?  Should we change the code to use `GetOidcTokenAsync()` in case of a `ServiceAccountCredential` too, or with that we should still use `GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()`, and `GetOidcTokenAsync()` should only be used with the `ComputeCredential`?

Comment: ID Tokens always use `https://accounts.google.com` as `iss` and are signed using the JWKS that's linked to in the [OIDC metadata](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration).

When you [authenticate by using a service account key](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#:~:text=Forming%20the%20JWT%20claim%20set), you're also creating a JWT, but that's not an ID Token, but a an assertion (also referred to as _JWT bearer_) that you can use to get an ID Token or AT. This JWT uses the SA's email address as issuer and is signed using an SA key.

Comment: A combination of `GetOidcTokenAsync` (once) and `oidcToken.GetAccessTokenAsync` (per request) works fine for SAs because the way of getting the OIDC token is different for the service account and compute credentials. However, in my case, the compute credentials fail when trying to get the token from the metadata server. Weird.